# How do I call a super class method from sub class object which has overridden?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I've been reading about [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and I've been through something interesting.

I have created two classes: a super class and a derived class. As you can see derived class inherits from the super class and using its method.

In the derived class I have overridden the method of super class.

So my question is: **I want to call the super class method from an object of a derived class**

For example:

```
derivedClass a = new derivedClass()
a.method();
```

I want `a.methood()` to execute the superclass method.

Is that possible?

Comment: If callers should be able to call either the base class's method or the derived class's method then you shouldn't be overriding the method in the first place, you should be making an entirely new method.

Comment: so its not possible ?

Comment: It's not a good idea, regardless of whether you can do it or not.

Comment: its just that i've heard of something "Subclass referenced as the superclass" and i still dont know how to do it and why they do it

Comment: And what was the context of that quote?  Did it provide any examples?  What did it say about doing that?

Comment: i've found it in oop concepts here is the link   https://stackify.com/oop-concept-polymorphism/       i dont understand the part where he starts to talk about late binding ,,and thanks bro for taking your time to answering me xD

Answer (score 6):

Summing up your question: You have a base class and a derived class. The derived class overrides a virtual method of the base class. Given an instance of the derived class, is it possible to force a call to the base class version of the method, instead of the derived class?

Short answer: From inside the class, yes.  From outside the class, no.

Essentially what you wish to do here is a *non virtual call to a virtual method*.  It is legal to do a non-virtual call to a base class method, but *only from inside the class*:

```
class B
{
  public virtual void M() { Console.WriteLine("B.M"); }
}
class D : B
{
  public override void M() { Console.WriteLine("D.M"); }
  public void BM() { base.M(); }
}
...
D d = new D();
d.M(); // D.M
d.BM(); // B.M
```

Now, for advanced players there *are* sneaky ways to call `B.M` with an instance of `D` as the receiver, and I'm not going to tell you what they are. **You should not attempt to do so.**  The CLR may flag such attempts as violations of its "verified code" rules. **The rules of virtual overriding are there for your convenience and safety. Do not attempt to do an end-run around those rules.**

Comment: thanks thats cool way to do so , if you may can you please tell me what is late binding , i found it in https://stackify.com/oop-concept-polymorphism/   and i dont understand this part " Subclass referenced as the superclass" why would you do so and how to do it in c#

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: well that was a silly typo. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Ezio: "Late binding" basically means that some decision about what code to call is made at runtime.  Virtual method calls are a form of late binding. See my article on the subject, where I describe many different forms of late binding: https://ericlippert.com/2012/02/06/what-is-late-binding/

Comment: @Ezio: By "subclass is referenced as superclass" the author means that you have a variable `Animal a = new Dog(); a.MakeNoise();` and the result is barking. We have a reference typed as the base class `Animal`, it *refers to* an instance of the derived class `Dog`, and the behaviour at runtime is late-bound: it barks. Given just the fact that we have an animal making noise we do not know if it is going to bark or roar until the call happens.

Comment: thank you so much ,that helped me alot , but why would we do so ,why would we do animal a = new dog while we could just do dog a = new dog () ?

Comment: @Ezio: You wouldn't.  You would write a method `void X(Animal a) { ... a.MakeNoise(); ... }`  and then you would call `X(new Dog())` and `X(new Cat())` and now you have assigned a dog to `a` once and a cat to `a` once, and sometimes you get barking and sometimes you get a meow.

Comment: thanks alot master , you are indeed wise , you really helped me , iwish ican upvote but im new ,again thank you so much

Comment: Wasn't sure if I got it wrong or if it was a type, otherwise I would have edited. Upvote for the brilliant noisy example (last 2 comments explain the answer much better than the answer itself :))

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I agree with you that the comments explain the answer better. [at] Eric Lippert: Thank you Eric for explaining late binding and virtual calls. Though I believe, if someone uses the virtual methods from base class by making non-virtual calls in some other method while having overridden the same virtual method in the derived class, that will be prime example of bad programming practice. Other programmers in your team will get confused, when trying to read story through the code. It is good example to explain underlying concepts.

Comment: @HiteshGaur: You are right that this is a confusing practice. There are sometimes reasons to do it. For example, suppose you have a base class that performs a task, and a derived class that does a security check and then performs the task. You want the derived class to be able to call the base class method that does the task, but you want the derived class's override to impose the security check by default. Maybe you also want to surface a way to do the task without the security check. That would follow the pattern I showed.

Comment: @EricLippert: It can meet your requirement and get the desired result, but it is neither maintainable nor sustainable coding practice. It will be better to refactor and redesign the method and derived classes, rather than use it in confusing manner. For the example with security check, it should be possible to incorporate logic with security check or without security check in the overridden method it'self.

Answer (score 2):

From outside the derived class it is not possible.  From within the derived class it is.

If you have these classes defined:

```
class A
{
  public virtual void Method1() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
class B : A
{
  override public void Method1() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
  public void BaseMethod1() { base.Method1(); }
}
```

You can execute the following:

```
  B b = new B();
  b.Method1(); //Outputs "B"
  b.BaseMethod1(); //Outputs "A"
  ((A)b).Method1(); //***Outputs "B" (even though you cast it as A)
```

If you change `overide` to `new` then the output of the last line is "A"

Comment: The question specifically mentions that the method is overridden.  Your example doesn't involve overriding the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling base method as per your requirement, if there is some condition, according to which you want to call it, you can use that condition as well.

```
public class SubClass : SuperClass
{
    public bool IsCallBaseClassMethod { get; set; }

    public override void Method(){
        if (IsCallBaseClassMethod)
        {
            base.Method();
        }
    }
}
```

Set the condition according to your requirement for the object and call the method for same object.

```
SubClass testObject = new SubClass();
testObject.IsCallBaseClassMethod  = true;
testObject.Method();
```